# Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\pythonProject\webscraping.py", line 17, in <module> search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) Error python

Tags: python, selenium

I am following a tutorial of a video on youtube about selenium and I got to this point
This is my code and it works fine until it gives you this massive error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject\webscraping.py", line 17, in <module>
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 602, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 773, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.53)
```

....

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

service=Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://www.techwithtim.net/")
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 's')
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting the same error as well. There seems to be an issue with Chromedriver 103. Your options are to wait for the new version, or to download Chrome Beta and use Chromedriver 104 with it.

A lot of people have also said to downgrade and use 102 instead.
Here's a link to a thread where others have reported the same problem:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10799

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
(//input[@name='s'])[2]
```

There's actually a second input with that value hidden use the above xpath.

Comment: so what exactly do I have to do the the code?

Comment: If you look at the search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 's') -> use (By.XPATH,"(//input[@name='s'])[2]")

Comment: I did search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//input[@name='s'])[2]") and it would still give pretty much the same error

Comment: Hmm oddly works on mine.